# SubSonic 3 Visual Studio Add-in

Tags: visual-studio, subsonic3

I'm look for a subsonic 3.0 Add-in tools for visual studio like what was provided for Subsonic 2. 
Any alternative tools. I find using the T4 templates annoying.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the project that contains the SubSonic templates, then click on the button at the top of Solution Explorer that that says Transform Text Templates, then wait. Use your output window to verify that SubSonic has refreshed all templates.

That's all there is to it.